# Where does geoserver store password and user for its postgresql database connection?

Tags: java, postgresql, psql, geoserver

I am unable to connect to GeoServer via localhost:8080/geoserver. When I try to connect, I get an Apache 404 error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - 
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.64 (Ubuntu)
```

Previously, I was able to connect and login to Geoserver with admin credentials.

After reviewing the geoserver error log file located at: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/logs/geoserver.log I found the following error, pointing to the connection:

```
java.io.IOException 
at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getDataStore(ResourcePool.java:630)
at org.geoserver...
at org.geoserver...
etc, etc
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "user_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct credentials.

The default username and password for geo server is 'admin' and 'geoserver'. 
Use correct credentials. You can change password in security section from web-application of geo server.

Comment: I was able to login previously. I have updated my question to further explain.

Comment: Are you able to login with same credentials in web app?

Comment: I am using cartaro. I can login to cartaro but cannot access GeoServer data.

Comment: I also cannot change password for "user_name" user by way of pgsql command in terminal. I was hoping to first find the location of the GeoServer connection to postgresql and then work on changing user name and password

Comment: I was able to connect to geoserver data previously from cartaro. I made some changes to the user name, likely resulting in disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer stores it's postgis passwords in the `datastore.xml` file in the relevant workspace directory.

But this won't help you as it encrypts them to prevent this sort of attack!

If you need to change the user name or password of your database connection, go to the datastore page and change them using the GUI. I think that layers configured on the store should be unaffected though I don't change my db stores very often so I can't be sure.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately can't find password changing in the graphical interface of Geoserver, in Datastores, for my Postgis connection.